# How can I merge two columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na

My dataframe has 2 columns which look similar to this:

```
a    b

NA   NA
yes  NA
no   NA
yes  NA
NA   yes
NA   no 
NA   NA
Na   yes
```

What I would then like as output is:

```
ab

NA
yes
no
yes
yes
no
NA
yes
```

Note that:

- In the original columns, there will always be an NA in any given row.
- For certain rows both columns will be NA

Any idea how I could get to the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `dplyr::coalesce`

```
> with(dat, dplyr::coalesce(a, b))
[1] NA    "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes" "no"  NA    "yes"
```

- `ifelse` for base R

```
> with(dat, ifelse(!is.na(a), a, ifelse(!is.na(b), b, NA)))
[1] NA    "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes" "no"  NA    "yes"
```

- `max.col` for base R

```
> dat[cbind(1:nrow(dat), max.col(!is.na(dat)))]
[1] NA    "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes" "no"  NA    "yes"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` you can wrap it pretty neatly:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>% summarize(ab = max(a,b, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(NA, "yes", "no", "yes", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "yes", "no", NA, "yes"))

require(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(ab = max(a,b, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
> apply(df, 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] NA    "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes" "no"  NA    "yes"
```

Assignment:

```
df$ab <- apply(df, 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import data: df => data.frame 
df <- structure(list(a = c(NA, "yes", "no", "yes", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "yes", "no", NA, "yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

# Function to coalesce vectors: br_coalesce => function
br_coalesce <- function(...){
   # Coalesce vectors or data.frames: res => vector
   res <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
         x <- replace(x, is.na(x), y[is.na(x)])
      },
      list(...)
   )
   # Explicitly define returned vectors: character vector => env
   return(res)
}

# Apply function: character vector / data.frame => stdout(console)
br_coalesce(df$a, df$b)
```

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   transmute(res = coalesce(a, b))
```

data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
fcoalesce(df$a, df$b)
```